# How Immutability is Achieved in Scala Streams?

Tags: scala, stream, immutability, memoization

It might become silly but I have question regarding to Scala Stream evaluation in immutable fashion.

Lets say I have a Stream like this (All lines executed in repl);

```
val a = Stream(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

**a: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)**

When I run following lines;

```
a(3);
a
```

I get ;

> scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, ?)

My first question is how this immutable structure gets changed ? I mean if did like this (assuming variable 'a' defined as 'var');
a = a(3) I might expect such result.

My other question is when I run following lines;

```
val a = Stream(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

**a: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)**

```
val b = a;
```

**b: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)**

```
b(5);
```

**scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ?)**

```
a
```

> scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ?)

As you can see in last part after executing 'a', its seems changed again.

If I try this kind of assignment with List type (as far as I know List is strict version of Stream) and do some transformation like drop,take etc.)

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val b = a;
b.dropRight(1)
```

variable 'a' and 'b' still is still List(1,2,3,4,5)

So how this happened and what is the point that I'm missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala Streams provide *[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)* - they are like lazy lists, but once elements have been generated, they are stored for future retrieval.

So when you "force" the Stream `b` to evaluate some of its elements by requesting the element at index 5, the original Stream `a` (which is the same Stream object) is also forced.

Key point: doing this doesn't *modify* the stream (it remains immutable), it just changes which elements have been evaluated and are memoized.

Your `Stream(1,?)` and `Stream(1,2,3,4,5,6,?)` are the same stream, just evaluated to a different degree:

```
scala> val a = Stream(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
a: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> val b = a

scala> a(3)
res9: Int = 4

scala> a
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, ?)

scala> b
res11: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, ?)

scala> Stream(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) == a
res12: Boolean = true

scala> Stream(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) == b
res13: Boolean = true
```